# Is php deg2rad() equal to mysql radians()

Tags: php, sql, mysql, trigonometry

Are these functions the same? If not, what is an appropriate php equivalent to mysql's `radians()`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Judging from their documentations ([`deg2rad`](http://php.net/deg2rad), [`radians`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_radians)), they seem to do the same.

And a quick verification on a simple test-case :

```
mysql> select radians(0), radians(45), radians(90);
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| radians(0) | radians(45)       | radians(90)     |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|          0 | 0.785398163397448 | 1.5707963267949 |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

And, in PHP :

```
var_dump(deg2rad(0), deg2rad(45), deg2rad(90));
```

also gives :

```
float 0
float 0.785398163397
float 1.57079632679
```

So, it seems they do quite the same...

Answer (score 7):

Consulting the documentation:

- [MySQL's RADIANS(x)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_radians): returns the argument `x`, converted from degrees to radians.
- [PHP's DEG2RAD()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.deg2rad.php): converts the number in degrees to the radian equivalent

...so yes, they are equivalent.

Was there something more specific you were looking for?